# How to avoid the "The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters." error message?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I get the following error when running the query below:

> The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a
>   maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend
>   the request.

How this happens is if you have access to a Primary Account, you automatically get access to any of that Primary Account's Sub Accounts - which can sometimes be several thousand Accounts (they are linked by ParentID).

The error gets triggered by the "acctList.Contains(...) and/or acctOpenList.Contains(...)" lines of the code because this where there might be over 2100 parameters.

How can I change this query to allow for more than 2100 parameters?  I assume there's a more efficient way of accomplishing this.

C# answers are acceptable - fluent in both.

```
Public Function GetRegisteredUserPendingTasks(currentAccountID As String, userID As Integer, username As String, emailAddress As String, ByVal includeTest As Boolean, isFederation As Boolean, includeAllGroups As Boolean) As IEnumerable(Of Participant)

    Dim AccountType As String()
    Dim type As String = IIf(isFederation, "federation", "registered")

    If includeTest Then
        AccountType = {"new", "test"}
    Else
        AccountType = {"new"}
    End If

    Dim allowedToSignAccountIDs = (From up In dc.UserPermissions Where up.UserID = userID AndAlso up.AllowSigning Select up.AccountID).ToList()
    Dim allowedToSignOpenAccountIDs = (From up In dc.UserPermissions Where up.UserID = userID AndAlso up.AllowOpenSigning AndAlso up.AllowOpenSigningQueue Select up.AccountID).ToList()

    Dim allAccountIDs = (From a In dc.Accounts Where (allowedToSignAccountIDs.Contains(a.AccountID) OrElse allowedToSignAccountIDs.Contains(a.ParentID)) And a.Status = "active" Select a.AccountID).ToList()
    Dim acctList = (From a In dc.Accounts Where (allowedToSignAccountIDs.Contains(a.AccountID) OrElse allowedToSignAccountIDs.Contains(a.ParentID)) And a.Status = "active" Select a.AccountID).ToList()

    Dim acctOpenList = (From a In dc.Accounts Where (allowedToSignOpenAccountIDs.Contains(a.AccountID) OrElse allowedToSignOpenAccountIDs.Contains(a.ParentID)) And a.Status = "active" Select a.AccountID).ToList()

    Dim q = From p In dc.Participants Order By p.TSCreate Descending, p.TransactionID
    q = q.Where(Function(p) _
                    (AccountType.Contains(p.Transaction.AccountType)) _
                And
                    (p.Transaction.StatusID = 2 And (p.StatusID = 2 Or p.StatusID = 6) And (p.AccessOrder Is Nothing Or p.AccessOrder = 1 Or p.Transaction.Participants.Any(Function(ps) ps.AccessOrder < p.AccessOrder And ps.StatusID = 4))) _
                And
                    (
                        (acctList.Contains(p.Transaction.AccountID) And (includeAllGroups = True Or (includeAllGroups = False And currentAccountID = p.Transaction.AccountID)) And p.EmailAddress = emailAddress And p.EmailAddress <> "" And p.Auth = "none") _
                        Or
                        (
                            p.Auth = type _
                            And
                            (
                                (acctList.Contains(p.Transaction.AccountID) And (includeAllGroups = True Or (includeAllGroups = False And currentAccountID = p.Transaction.AccountID)) And p.AuthData.ToLower() = username.ToLower()) _
                                Or
                                (acctOpenList.Contains(p.Transaction.AccountID) And (includeAllGroups = True Or (includeAllGroups = False And currentAccountID = p.Transaction.AccountID)) And p.AuthData = "")
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
    Return q

End Function
```

---

**UPDATE** per juharr's comments

I removed `.ToList()` on everything (and the `allAccountIDs` which was unnecessary legacy code) but now I get:

> Queries with local collections are not supported.

```
Public Function GetRegisteredUserPendingTasks(currentAccountID As String, userID As Integer, username As String, emailAddress As String, ByVal includeTest As Boolean, isFederation As Boolean, includeAllGroups As Boolean) As IEnumerable(Of Participant)

    Dim AccountType As String()
    Dim type As String = IIf(isFederation, "federation", "registered")

    If includeTest Then
        AccountType = {"new", "test"}
    Else
        AccountType = {"new"}
    End If

    Dim allowedToSignAccountIDs = (From up In dc.UserPermissions Where up.UserID = userID AndAlso up.AllowSigning Select up.AccountID)
    Dim allowedToSignOpenAccountIDs = (From up In dc.UserPermissions Where up.UserID = userID AndAlso up.AllowOpenSigning AndAlso up.AllowOpenSigningQueue Select up.AccountID)

    Dim acctList = (From a In dc.Accounts Where (allowedToSignAccountIDs.Contains(a.AccountID) OrElse allowedToSignAccountIDs.Contains(a.ParentID)) And a.Status = "active" Select a.AccountID)

    Dim acctOpenList = (From a In dc.Accounts Where (allowedToSignOpenAccountIDs.Contains(a.AccountID) OrElse allowedToSignOpenAccountIDs.Contains(a.ParentID)) And a.Status = "active" Select a.AccountID)

    Dim q = From p In dc.Participants Order By p.TSCreate Descending, p.TransactionID
    q = q.Where(Function(p) _
                    (AccountType.Contains(p.Transaction.AccountType)) _
                And
                    (p.Transaction.StatusID = 2 And (p.StatusID = 2 Or p.StatusID = 6) And (p.AccessOrder Is Nothing Or p.AccessOrder = 1 Or p.Transaction.Participants.Any(Function(ps) ps.AccessOrder < p.AccessOrder And ps.StatusID = 4))) _
                And
                    (
                        (acctList.Contains(p.Transaction.AccountID) And (includeAllGroups = True Or (includeAllGroups = False And currentAccountID = p.Transaction.AccountID)) And p.EmailAddress = emailAddress And p.EmailAddress <> "" And p.Auth = "none") _
                        Or
                        (
                            p.Auth = type _
                            And
                            (
                                (acctList.Contains(p.Transaction.AccountID) And (includeAllGroups = True Or (includeAllGroups = False And currentAccountID = p.Transaction.AccountID)) And p.AuthData.ToLower() = username.ToLower()) _
                                Or
                                (acctOpenList.Contains(p.Transaction.AccountID) And (includeAllGroups = True Or (includeAllGroups = False And currentAccountID = p.Transaction.AccountID)) And p.AuthData = "")
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
    Return q

End Function
```

**UPDATE 2**

This seems to have fixed the issue and looks more efficient as well:

```
Public Function GetRegisteredUserPendingTasks(currentAccountID As String, userID As Integer, username As String, emailAddress As String, ByVal includeTest As Boolean, isFederation As Boolean, includeAllGroups As Boolean) As IEnumerable(Of Participant)

    Dim AccountType As String()
    Dim type As String = IIf(isFederation, "federation", "registered")

    If includeTest Then
        AccountType = {"new", "test"}
    Else
        AccountType = {"new"}
    End If

    Dim allowedToSignAccountIDs = (From up In dc.UserPermissions Where up.UserID = userID AndAlso up.AllowSigning AndAlso up.Account.Status = "active" Select up.AccountID)
    Dim allowedToSignOpenAccountIDs = (From up In dc.UserPermissions Where up.UserID = userID AndAlso up.AllowOpenSigning AndAlso up.AllowOpenSigningQueue AndAlso up.Account.Status = "active" Select up.AccountID)

    Dim q = From p In dc.Participants Order By p.TSCreate Descending, p.TransactionID
    q = q.Where(Function(p) AccountType.Contains(p.Transaction.AccountType))
    q = q.Where(Function(p) p.Transaction.StatusID = 2 And (p.StatusID = 2 Or p.StatusID = 6) And (p.AccessOrder Is Nothing Or p.AccessOrder = 1 Or p.Transaction.Participants.Any(Function(ps) ps.AccessOrder < p.AccessOrder And ps.StatusID = 4)))

    q = q.Where(Function(p) _
                    (
                        ((allowedToSignAccountIDs.Contains(p.Transaction.AccountID) OrElse allowedToSignAccountIDs.Contains(p.Transaction.Account.ParentID)) And (includeAllGroups = True Or (includeAllGroups = False And currentAccountID = p.Transaction.AccountID)) And p.EmailAddress = emailAddress And p.EmailAddress <> "" And p.Auth = "none") _
                        Or
                        (
                            p.Auth = type _
                            And
                            (
                                ((allowedToSignAccountIDs.Contains(p.Transaction.AccountID) OrElse allowedToSignAccountIDs.Contains(p.Transaction.Account.ParentID)) And (includeAllGroups = True Or (includeAllGroups = False And currentAccountID = p.Transaction.AccountID)) And p.AuthData.ToLower() = username.ToLower()) _
                                Or
                                ((allowedToSignOpenAccountIDs.Contains(p.Transaction.AccountID) OrElse allowedToSignOpenAccountIDs.Contains(p.Transaction.Account.ParentID)) And (includeAllGroups = True Or (includeAllGroups = False And currentAccountID = p.Transaction.AccountID)) And p.AuthData = "")
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
    Return q

End Function
```

Comment: Don't `ToList` `acctList` and `acctOpenList` that way they will be sub-queries instead of lists of parameters and you'll reduce the number of DB calls.

Comment: You could use a join, or raw sql.

Comment: @juharr Then I get `Queries with local collections are not supported.`

Comment: @RichC You'll need to remove `ToList` from `allowedToSignOpenAccountIDs` and `allowedToSignAccountIDs` as well.  Also `allAccountIDs` doesn't seem to be needed

Comment: @juharr I updated the question per your comments

Comment: @RichC I guess EF doesn't support `Contains` with sub-queries unfortunately.  The alternative is to rewrite this into one query by using joins or alternatively to do the `Contains` filtering in memory vs in the DB, but that might not be performant based on the amount of data you might get back.

Comment: This is linq-to-sql and not EF.  This is in our legacy code.  We use EF now which probably doesn't have the issue.  I'm looking into rewriting using joins to see if that results any better. thanks, @juharr!